# Google Account Credential change account/logout

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I'm working with Google Calendar API. And I used code from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android.

There is something like `GoogleAccountCredential` and I set account name to this object using methods: `chooseAccount` and `OnActivityResult`. But I have no idea how could I change account after I already set it in my application. I want user to allow change account whenever he want by clicking button to logout from selected account.

I made new button and tried this in `onClick` method:

```
SharedPreferences settings =
                    getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, "");
            editor.apply();



            mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(null);
```

But after,click the button and try to call calendar api again, it just stop.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. I put this in the `onClick` method(for logout button):

```
SharedPreferences settings =
                    getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, "");
            editor.apply();



            mCredential.setSelectedAccountName("");
            startActivityForResult(
                    mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                    REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER_CHANGE);
```

and here is part of `onActivityResult`:

```
case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER_CHANGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                    data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName =
                        data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    SharedPreferences settings =
                            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.apply();
                    mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                }
            }
            break;
```

It seems to work well, after click logout button user can again choose acc. But I'm not sure it's the best way to change account. Any other ideas?